# List with buttons - only first button registers

Tags: android

I have implemented a ListView, each element of which contains a checkbox and a button. I have written an adapter for the view as follows:

```
public class myadapter extends SimpleAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public myadapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View view = null;

        Log.i("xx","getView called: position="+position);

        if (convertView != null)
        {
            view = convertView;
        } 
        else 
        {      
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, parent, false);
        }

        Button buttonEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.editbut);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        buttonEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Log.i("xx","Button pressed! position ="+position);
            }
        });
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) 
            {
                Log.i("xx","Checkbox changed! position ="+position);
            }
          });

        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

At runtime, if I click on a button in the top row of my list I always see "Button pressed! position = 0" in the log output. Similarly, if I click on the checkbox I see "Checkbox changed! position=0". The problem comes if I click on a button on any other element in the list. Sometimes I see the correct log message, but other times I see nothing at all. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** here's my custom_row_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"         
                android:textSize="16sp"         
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#FFFF00"        
                android:layout_width="match_parent"         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"         
                android:textSize="12sp"         
                android:textStyle="bold"      
                android:layout_width="match_parent"         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text3" 
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >



    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editbut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Edit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are u using "view" when u could have used convertView directly instead?

Comment: every time you add a new button on the row. the better approach is to save button object in static class and add only when the view is null.

Comment: @user735675: I'm just copying code from elsewhere - I don't claim to understand it.

Comment: @Mick don't use this "view" object at all as it makes the whole thing look more complicated. Just use the convertView in all places and and return convertView itself. It must work then.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View view = convertView;

    Log.i("xx","getView called: position="+position);

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = convertView;             
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, parent, false);
    }
    Button buttonEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.editbut);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - it made no difference - exactly the same symptoms

Comment: change this to return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); to return view;

Comment: "return view;"... well that sort of worked in as much as I now do see the correct log message - but now none of the text contest of the list items are displayed.

Comment: get those textview like how you did for button, check box and set text to those related view depends on requirement...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13943/discussion-between-rajareddy-p-and-mick)

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
Button buttonEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.editbut);
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
          buttonEdit.setTag(String.valueOf(positin));
          cb.setTag(String.valueOf(positin));
          buttonEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {   
          public void onClick(View arg0)
           {
           Log.i("xx","Button pressed! position ="+arg0.getTag());
             }
           });
       cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) 
        {
        Log.i("xx","Checkbox changed! position ="+arg0.getTag(););
         }
          });
```

you are using  `OnClickListener`() inner as a inner class. for inner class the value of position remains zero. until you setTag() on button and then getTag from button.

Comment: Sorry - it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the superclass value, with convertview as a parameter.

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

but you are doing this:

```
if (convertView != null)
    {
        view = convertView;
    } 
    else 
    {      
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, parent, false);
    }
```

If convertView is null, you are inflating a new view, but you are not returning it.

my suggestion is

```
return view;
```

instead of

```
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

That should be enough

Comment: See comments under RajaReddy's answer.

Comment: "but now none of the text content of the list items are displayed."

Your code looks like you are not inserting any text on the controls